# Copy rows based on one cell value and in reference to another cell value and paste on a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have to create a report where I get a raw data with a list of transactions, I need my macro to send each transaction to its respective sheets based on if Portfolio name at C Column

I manged to do that, but now I need Transaction of Nokia that fall under 'Cash' from the below given reference sheet, to paste under sheet "Nokia - Cash"

[image: Raw Data Workbook UPDATED]

[image: Reference Sheet]

Can someone please help me build the 2nd part of my code which helps to move the if C=Nokia and J = Semi Paid then move to Nokia - Cash?

Comment: Is sheet21 part of the Row workbook?

Comment: And is it possible to change Category "Office supplies" to just say "Office", so that the destination sheet name can be determined by the card and the category, without having to hard-code things in the code?

Comment: And can the sheet "Master Card - Office" be renamed "Mastercard - Office", for the same reason?

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to the previous question I have answered.

You don't have to worry about creating the sheets and naming them, the code handles it. It also skips the items which are not found in reference sheet.

It matches the *description item* with *item in your reference sheet*, then concats *card name* with the *matched item's category name* in order to name the relevant sheet. If this sheet does not exist, it creates and pass the row data, otherwise simply pass the row data.

```
Sub MyClients()
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, matchrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim wsname As String
lastrow = Worksheets("Raw").Cells(Worksheets("Raw").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = Worksheets("Raw").Cells(1, Worksheets("Raw").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To lastrow
    On Error Resume Next
    matchrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Raw").Cells(i, 10).Value, Worksheets("Reference").Range("A:A"), 0)
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find item: '" & Worksheets("Raw").Cells(i, 10).Value & "' within reference sheet. Skipping row no: " & i
        GoTo skip:
    End If
    wsname = Worksheets("Raw").Cells(i, 3).Value & " - " & Worksheets("Reference").Cells(matchrow, 2).Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Worksheets("Raw").Cells(i, 1).Value
    For j = 1 To lastcol - 1
        Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, j) = Worksheets("Raw").Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = wsname
        For j = 1 To lastcol
            Worksheets(wsname).Cells(1, j) = Worksheets("Raw").Cells(1, j).Value
        Next j
        Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Worksheets("Raw").Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 1 To lastcol - 1
            Worksheets(wsname).Cells(Worksheets(wsname).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, j) = Worksheets("Raw").Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
    End If
skip:
Next i
Worksheets("Raw").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! This worked perfectly. Sadly the code is too intense for me to edit. The sheet details i gave earlier were just an example sheet, i thought i would be able to mend the code per my requirements, but i couldn't. 

Could you please help me edit the code to match my actual workbook?

I have edited my original post to reflect my workbook

Comment: What is the data between columns E and I, do you need them to be copied as well? What is the data after column J? Do you need it as well?

Comment: I actually hide them to show you column J. I would need all the data of that row copied.

Comment: I keep getting subscript errors when i tried to mess with the code you made, sorry i am asking you again

Comment: @Sahil Bakshi I updated the code, but haven't tried it. Please check if it works for you.